# Regex to match many times

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a type definition

```
def euro : t1 -> t2 -> t3 (and this pattern my repeat further in other examples)
```

I came up with this regex

```
^def ([^\s]*)\s:\s([^\s]*)(\s->\s[^\s]*)*
```

But while it matches `euro` and `t1` it

- then matches `-> t2` rather than `t2`
- fails to match anything with `t3`

I can't see what I am doing wrong, and my goal is to capture

```
euro t1 t2 t3
```

as four separate items, and what I currently get is

```
0: "def euro : t1 -> t2 -> t3"
1: "euro"
2: "t1"
3: " -> t3"
```

Comment: The regex matches the whole string, which does include the substring `t2`, and the substring `-> t2`? Did you want `t2` in its own capture group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a [repeated capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) in JS regex, all but the last values will be "dropped", re-written upon each subsequent iteration.

> When creating a regular expression that needs a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to grab part of the text matched, a common mistake is to [repeat](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) the capturing group instead of capturing a repeated group. The difference is that the repeated capturing group will capture only the last iteration, while a group capturing another group that's repeated will capture all iterations.

The way out can be capturing the whole substring  and then split it. Here is an example:

```js
var s = "def euro : t1 -> t2 -> t3";
var rx = /^def (\S*)\s:\s(\S*)((?:\s->\s\S*)*)/;
var res = [];
var m = s.match(rx);
if (m) {
  res = [m[1], m[2]];
  for (var s of m[3].split(" -> ").filter(Boolean)) {
     res.push(s);
  }
}
console.log(res);
```

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `def`  - a literal substring
- `(\S*)` - Capturing group 1: 0+ non-whitespace chars
- `\s:\s` - a `:` enclosed with single whitespaces
- `(\S*)` - Capturing group 2: 0+ non-whitespace chars

  - `((?:\s->\s\S*)*)` - Capturing group 3: 0+ repetitions of the following pattern sequences:
  - `\s->\s` - whitespace, `->`, whitespace
  - `\S*` - 0+ non-whitespace chars

Comment: @SimonH That is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do). It is only used for grouping patterns, hence there is no need of the capturing construct overhead.

Answer (score 0):

**Details**:

`?:` - creates a *non-capturing group*

`$1` - recieves the result of *first capturing* group i.e., `\w+`

`\s[\:\-\>]+\s` - matches `" : "` or `" -> "`

`\w+` - matches repeating *alphanumeric* pattern

```js
let str = 'def euro : t1 -> t2 -> t3';
let regex = /(?:def\s|\s[\:\-\>]+\s)(\w+)/g;

let match = str.replace(regex, '$1\n').trim().split('\n');
console.log(match);
```

Comment: You should not use `[\w\d]+` since `\w+` will do the same job. `\w` matches ASCII letters, digits or `_`.